# Problems with loading events from rails generated JSON to FullCalendar by Angularjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm new to AngularJS, and I've been trying this for a while but really cant solve my problem.

1. When I was using ui-calendar for Angular, it has the 
   `"TypeError: undefined is not a function"`
   problem, and the calendar wont even show up.

   I solved it by wrapping the scope.calendar to $(scope.calendar) in the calendar.js. 
   I saw other saying its because the dependency, but when the page is running I can find the js sources in the page like the following:

   > `<script src="/assets/angular.min.js?body=1"></script>`
   >   `<script src="/assets/fullcalendar.js?body=1"></script>`
   >   `<script src="/assets/calendar.js?body=1"></script>`
   >   `<script src="/assets/angular-resource.min.js?body=1"></script>`
   >   So is this a problem of dependency or?
2. The second problem I have is loading events from rails-generated json into my calendar.
   $scope.events are events I wrote in javescript, $scope.eventjson are events from json, and only the $scope.events are loading into the calendar
   I have this code in my rails controller:

   > `respond_to do |format|
   >      format.json { render :json => {:title=> "event", :start => "2014-04-08 10:00:00" }.to_json }
   >    end`

   And this is my Angular Controller:

   > `controller('myCtrl', ['$log', '$scope','$q', '$resource', '$http'].concat(function($log, $scope, $q, $resource, $http){
   >        var date, d, m, y, Event;
   >        date = new Date();
   >        d = date.getDate();
   >        m = date.getMonth();
   >        y = date.getFullYear();
   >        Event = $resource("/calendar.json");
   >        $scope.eventjson = Event.get();
   >        $scope.eventjson.$promise.then(function(result){
   >        $scope.eventjson = result;
   >        });
   >   $scope.events = [
   >     {
   >       title: 'All Day Event',
   >       start: "2014-4-10 10:00:00",
   >       allDay: false
   >     }, {
   >       title: 'All Day Event',
   >       start: "2014-4-11 10:00:00",
   >       allDay: false
   >     }
   >   ];
   >   $scope.uiConfig = {
   >     calendar: {
   >       height: 350,
   >       editable: true,
   >       header: {
   >         left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
   >         center: 'title',
   >         right: 'today prev,next'
   >       },
   >       defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
   >       dayClick: $scope.dayClick,
   >       eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
   >       eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
   >       eventClick: $scope.eventClick,
   >       viewRender: $scope.renderView
   >     }
   >   };
   >   $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events] //this one works
   >   //$scope.eventSources = [$scope.events, $scope.eventjson]  //got Error: $interpolate:interr
   >   //$scope.eventSources = [$scope.eventjson] //this one shows nothing
   >   }));`

   And my view:

   `<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources">`

I personally think its related with angular's promise, but I think that shouldn't be because there is `$scope.watch` in the calendar.js which means it should be watching $scope.eventSources changes. But when using break points I can see $scope.eventsources are not loading value for `$scope.eventSources = [$scope.eventjson]`.

I've been working on this for two days, really appreciate if someone can give some help.

Comment: I solved my first question. Its because the sequence of js sources, FullCalendar.js and Calendar.js should be put before angular.js